# What is linear extension g of f such that $||f||=||g||$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Consider a functional $f$ on the Euclidean
plane $R^2$ defined by $f(x) = ax_1+bx_2$ where $x = (x_1,x_2)$. What is its linear extension
$g$ to $R^3$ such that $||f||=||g||$ ?

I took
 $g(x_1,x_2,x_3)= ax_1+bx_2+cx_3$ but here $||f||\ne||g||$

Comment: It is $g(x_1, x_2, x_3)=ax_1+bx_2$.

Comment: yes thank you, is there any other than it?

Comment: No, it is unique .

Comment: is it so? how to prove uniqueness?

Comment: but theorem says there exists **a**  linear extension

Comment: We have $\|f\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\|g\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. If $\|f\|=\|g\|$ then $c=0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57108/discussion-between-infinite-and-ntt).